# useReducer with an async action to make an API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form where there is a field called `description` where when a button called `query` is clicked it will perform a `POST` request and then send the text in the field `description` in the body of the request.

I am using useReducer for this and unsure how structure the action and the useEffect when the user clicks on the `query` button.

`Action for querying the data(I am not sure what to return in this case)`

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "query": {
    return {
      ...state,
    };
  }
}
```

`Making the POST request and setting the JSON data in state which is then displayed(Takes as input the data from the field description)`

```
const fetchData = async (desc) => {
  const response = await fetch("/rank", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ terms: desc }),
  }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
  const dataJSON = await response.json().catch((e) => console.log(e));
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log("OK");
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = (dataJSON && dataJSON.message) || response.status;
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
  setData(dataJSON.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData(description);
}, [description]);
```

`Button for making the query`

```
<Button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch({ type: "query" });
  }}
>
```

All of this works but the issue is that the `useEffect` hook is getting triggered even when I do not click the button to query as I do not know how to set up the action for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point to useEffect to fetchData. you want that function called only on Submit, and not on every state update.

also you have some sort of `setData`. this would result in a duplicated state, once you use useReducer. I would suggest to remove this data `state` if you are using reducer here.

I would recommend to onClick action, to call fetchData and dispatch action on success.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
  const response = await fetch("/rank", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ terms: description }),
  })
  const dataJSON = await response.json();
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log("OK");
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = (dataJSON && dataJSON.message) || response.status;
    throw error;
  }
  dispatch({ type: "query", data: dataJSON.data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

then your reducer at your reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case "query":
    return {...state, action.data };
  default:
    return state;
}
```

you could also add some extra dispatch action, like `loading`, `success` and `error` to handle these cases if needed.

Comment: I am getting an error from `{...state, action.data }`. It says `unreachable code detected`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I cannot see where things are located and what has access to what. How does: `dispatch({ type: "query", data: dataJSON.data });` get access to the reducer?